# Anaconda Jupyter R install

Tags: r, anaconda

Hi I tried to install R for my Jupyter notebook (Anaconda) and used the below command in my Anaconda prompt "conda install -c r r-essentials". But there is an error like below: any suggestions (especially missing package).

```
(C:\Anaconda3) C:\windows\system32>conda install -c r r-essentials
 Using Anaconda Cloud api site https://api.anaconda.org
 Fetching package metadata ...Could not connect to 
 https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs
/pro/noarch/
Could not connect to https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-64/
 Could not connect to https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/win-64/
...Could not connect to https://conda.anaconda.org/r/win-64/
.Could not connect to https://conda.anaconda.org/r/noarch/
```

.Could not connect to https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch/
 .
  Solving package specifications: .
  Error: Package missing in current win-64 channels:
  - r-essentials

You can search for packages on anaconda.org with

```
anaconda search -t conda r-essentials
```

(C:\Anaconda3) C:\windows\system32>

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this alternative. It worked on my colleague's machine:

> conda create -n my-r-env -c r r-essentials

Another approach would be to reinstall Anaconda and execute

> conda install -c r r-essentials

Let us know if it worked.